# Validation failed or similar event using MicrosoftMvcValidation.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a validation failed or similar event raised by the MicrosoftMvcValidation.js framework and if so how do I go about hooking into it ?

Currently I have a "global" function that displays a progressing overlay on submit of a form but when validation fails I have no way of removing this ....

Comment: As it turns out there is no event raised, the validation framework simply calls preventDefault() without raising any event.